# windows OpenDialog open at background of other forms of application in Delphi, How to bring it at front?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I am using OpenDialog in Delphi 5. My problem is it opens at the back of My Application forms. I set My application form at the TOP using following code

```
if UpperCase(SmSession.ApplicationName) = 'MYAPP' then
begin
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TOPMOST;
  exit;
end
```

, so the windows dialog box might be at the back. How can I take it to front without changing my application forms code ?

This is my code to openDialog:

```
EditParent.OpenDlg.InitialDir := EditParent.FDefaultDir;
EditParent.OpenDlg.FileName := EditParent.FFileName;

if EditParent.OpenDlg.Execute then
Begin
  SplitFileDir(EditParent.OpenDlg.FileName, TmpDir, TmpFile);
  if EditParent.ShowOnlyFileName then
    EditParent.FileName := TmpFile
  else
    EditParent.FileName := EditParent.OpenDlg.FileName;
  EditParent.Directory := TmpDir;
  EditParent.SetPeerDirectoryBrowser;
End;
EditParent.OpenDlg.Free;
inherited Click;
```

end;

Comment: You need to hack the Delphi 5 dialogs code to use the correct window handle as the dialog's owner.

Comment: You 'free' OpenDlg? Why do you do that?

Comment: `BringWindowToTop(OpenDialog1.Handle);`

Comment: to Free up the dialog

Comment: BringWindowToTop(EditParent.OpenDlg.Handle); I tried this sir but not working. @Sami

Comment: How to do this @David

Comment: You need to arrange that the `hwndOwner` of the `OPENFILENAME` struct is set to the window handle of your always on top main form. Read about owned windows here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows

Comment: @Sami This is a Windows file dialog. I don't think that you understand the issues at all here. For a start, when would you call `BringWindowToTop`? The dialog's window handle is not available at any point in the code above. Furthermore, bringing it to the top is one thing, how would you keep it there. Window ownership is what does that. You also should read the link in my comment above.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan K

Comment: Sir,  will you please give a example. I have just started to work on Delphi @DavidHeffernan

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What about `if EditParent.OpenDlg.Execute(Self.Handle) then`?

Comment: @Sami Not available in Delphi 5. In those older versions handling of window ownership was pretty broken in the VCL. They started to improve matters from Delphi 7.

Comment: @user7424581 It's going to involve hacking the VCL. I don't have Delphi 5 at hand. If I were you I'd just ignore the VCL file dialog classes and call `GetOpenFileName` directly. Or if you don't need to support XP you could go ahead and use the Vista common item dialogs, `IFileDialog` and friends.

Comment: if EditParent.OpenDlg.Execute(Self.Handle) it gives error too many actual parameter @sami

Comment: Please try to give example. It's all goes bounce... @DavidHeffernan

Comment: There are plenty of examples out there of how to call `GetOpenFileName`. It's also well documented on MSDN. You just need to call it passing the window handle of the main form as the owner. I haven't got time to write yet another example. Sometimes you don't get an instant solution where somebody else writes the code for you. Sometimes you need to put the hard yards in. I suspect that you knew nothing of window ownership until today. It takes time for it to sink in. Did you read that MSDN link that I gave you. Do you understand why window ownership is the key to the problem?

Comment: Ok. I will search on GetOpenFileName

Comment: Maybe there are better sets of common dialog components on torry.net / I remember there even was a library dissecting those common dialogs back to a form with components, so you could enhance it adding your own components to it. It worked albeit VERY slow. Then, computers today are faster than in 1999.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  after reading above link i tried following  SetWindowPos(EditParent.OpenDlg.Handle,HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOZORDER);   but not working.

Comment: also change delphi code:                                                                          { TComponent }
constructor TComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
parma:TCreateParams;
begin

  FComponentStyle := [csInheritable];
  parma.ExStyle := Parma.ExStyle or WS_EX_TOPMOST;
  if AOwner <> nil then AOwner.InsertComponent(Self);

end;

Comment: { TOpenDialog }

constructor TOpenDialog.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
parma:TCreateParams;
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
   Parma.ExStyle := Parma.ExStyle or WS_EX_TOPMOST;
  FHistoryList := TStringList.Create;
  FOptions := [ofHideReadOnly, ofEnableSizing];
  FFiles := TStringList.Create;
  FFilterIndex := 1;
  FFileEditStyle := fsEdit;


end;

Comment: None of that looks like it will help. You need to get the window ownership set correctly.

Comment: how to get windows ownership ? please provide any link so that i can refer it.

Comment: I have applied  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TOPMOST; WS_EX_TOPMOST style to form at the of Form creation. I want to change it,after creation to set it at background. is there any way for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This Property I was using for keep my application window on top always. Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TOPMOST;

now i commented this line and use another following property 
          Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
          Params.WndParent := GetDesktopWindow;
it works.